# Simple C++ Class add and display Song object

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class

I am new to C++ and am having issues when running this code, I have no idea where I have gone wrong.

I am just trying to make a simple Song class, then add and display an instance of the song object.

The error is saying that allot of my Methods are already defined in projectName.obj. I am also getting unresolved external symbol on IDSeed.

I am using visual studio 2017.

***Main***

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Song.h"
#include "Song.cpp"


int main()
{

Song testSong("Evil Tram", "Catz N dogz");
testSong.setGenre("Tech House");

testSong.display();

return 0;
}
```

***Song.cpp***

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Song.h"


Song::Song()
{
    m_title = "";
    m_album = "";//change to class
    m_artist = "";//change to class
    m_genre = "";//change to enum
    m_ID = 0;
    IDSeed = 0;

}

Song::Song(string title, string artist)
{
    m_title = title;
    m_album = "No Album";
    m_genre = "No Genre";
    m_artist = artist;

    IDSeed++;
    m_ID = IDSeed;
}

string Song::getTitle() const
{
    return m_title;
}

string Song::getAlbum() const
{
    return m_album;
}

string Song::getArtist() const
{
    return m_artist;
}

string Song::getGenre() const
{
    return m_genre;
}

int Song::getID() const
{
    return m_ID;
}

void Song::setTitle(string title)
{
    m_title = title;
}

void Song::setAlbum(string album)
{
    m_album = album;
}

void Song::setArtist(string artist)
{
    m_artist = artist;
}

void Song::setGenre(string genre)
{
    m_genre = genre;
}

void Song::setID(int id)
{
    m_ID = id;
}

void Song::display() const
{
    cout << m_title << ", " << m_album << ", "
        << m_artist << ", " << m_genre << endl;
}


Song::~Song()
{
}

ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, Song & s)
{
    out << s.m_title << ", " << s.m_album << ", "
        << s.m_artist << ", " << s.m_genre <<  endl;
    return out;
}

istream & operator>>(istream & in, Song & s)
{
    in >> s.m_title >> s.m_album >> s.m_artist >> s.m_genre;
    return in;
}
```

***Song.h***

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ostream>
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ostream;
using std::istream;

class Song
{
private:
#pragma region Variables
    string m_title;
    string m_album;//change to class
    string m_artist;//change to class
    string m_genre;//change to enum
    int m_ID;
    static int IDSeed;
#pragma endregion

public:
    Song();
    Song(string title, string artist);

#pragma region Getters
    string getTitle() const;
    string getAlbum()const;
    string getArtist()const;
    string getGenre()const;
    int getID()const;
#pragma endregion

#pragma region Setters
    void setTitle(string title);
    void setAlbum(string album);
    void setArtist(string artist);
    void setGenre(string genre);
    void setID(int id);
#pragma endregion

#pragma region Methods
    void display() const;
#pragma endregion

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out,
        Song& s);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& in,
        Song& s);

    ~Song();//destructer
};
```

Comment: Remove #include "Song.cpp" from Main then try to compile it

Comment: Don't use #include with .ccp files. The .h file provides prototypes for the functions/methods in the corresponding .cpp file.

Comment: Where did you declare IDseed object? I can't see any declaration..

Comment: Thank you I thought I had to include the cpp file, Yes IDSeed is a Static int its in Song.h under variables and i set it to 0 in song.cpp I don't need getters or setters for it as I am starting it at o and increasing it to set the songs id.

Comment: Ok so it works when I remove static.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by removing the #include song.cpp and placing the static keyword in the cpp file instead of the .h